# Have executable, but need to identify source code

Tags: c#, exe, projects-and-solutions

I am working in legacy code with the author long gone and documentation completely absent. I have an application running in production that I am trying to track down the source code in Team Foundation Server. I have been unable to find it in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the projects I have looked at.

Does anyone know where to look or how to search to find which solution makes that executable? I have found no similar questions in searching here.

Comment: I don't know any way either, but a colleague sent me a link to dotPeek a while back. Maybe it can be useful?  https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: I would start by checking the project files that have the executable fn in them. In the latest versions of VS, the project file contains an xml element called <AssemblyName> with the name of the executable or library. this could be a tedious process though.

Comment: Okay. The `AssemblyInfo.cs` is generated from Visual Studio when you, for example, add a COMPANY tag in the properties page. As far as I know, this file(s) are not necessary to build the application.

Comment: Also, it is VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully found the source code by pasting the .csproj into a text editor and looking for the  tag. That was the kind of answer I was looking for. Tip O' the hat to xDJR1875.